# Cannot clone io::Error in 1.0.0 beta

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I just began learning Rust, but since updating to the beta version, I am facing many compilation errors that weren't there before.
One of these is related to `clone`, here is my code:

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;

pub fn main() {

    let ref path = match env::args().nth(1) {
            Some(path) => path,
            None => panic!("file path is missing!"), };

    let file = match File::open(&path) {
            Ok(file) => file,
            Err(_) => panic!("could not open {}", path), };

    let mut iter = BufReader::new(file).lines();
    let mut opt = iter.next();

    let str = opt.clone().unwrap().unwrap();

    // some code omitted
}
```

And this is the error:

> test.rs:19:19: 19:26 error: type `core::option::Option<core::result::Result<collections::string::String, std::io::error::Error>>` does not implement any method in scope named `clone`
>   test.rs:19     let str = opt.clone().unwrap().unwrap();

I need the `clone` because I use `opt` in other parts of my code.

Is my code at fault, or has something I don't know about changed in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the the error message is confusing you, so let's look at it:

```
type `core::option::Option<core::result::Result<collections::string::String, std::io::error::Error>>` does not implement any method in scope named `clone`
```

Let's shorten up the types a bit:

```
type `Option<Result<String, io::Error>>` does not implement any method in scope named `clone`
```

So, let's check out [`Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). It says it implements `Clone`:

```
impl<T> Clone for Option<T> where T: Clone + Clone
```

I'm not sure what's going on with `Clone + Clone`, but this says "I can implement `Clone` if my contained type implements `Clone`. So let's look at the contained type, [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). It says something similar:

```
impl<T, E> Clone for Result<T, E> where E: Clone + Clone, T: Clone + Clone
```

Ok, so let's check [`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html). It says it supports `Clone`. How about [`io::Error`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html)?

This does **not** implement `Clone`, so therefore the whole type cannot implement it.

So how do you fix it? In you case, you don't care about the failures (you just unwrap), so do that first:

```
let str = opt.unwrap().unwrap().clone();
```

This clones the `String` instead of all the intermediate state. This may even be slightly more efficient, as you clone less data.

Comment: Looks like the Clone + Clone thing is a Rustdoc bug, it's happening for Copy too..

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `std::io::Error` doesn't implement `Clone`, which is the problem.  I don't see any real reason why it *couldn't*, so I assume this is simply an oversight.  It might be worth filing an issue to support it.

In the mean time, the simplest workaround I can think of is to replace the `Error` with something you *can* clone.  The quickest way to do that is to turn it into a `String`:

```
let opt = opt.map(|r| r.map_err(|e| format!("{}", e)));
```

If you want to keep the actual `Error` value around, you could try moving it into an `Rc` so that you have shared ownership.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `.clone()` to work on `Result<T, E>`, both `T` and `E` must implement the `Clone` trait.

In this case, you deal with a `Result<String, Error>`, however `Error` does not implement `Clone`!